# HM-10 does not exit AT mode

Tags: bluetooth, hm-10

I have a HM-10 (probably a clone) which I managed to get into AT mode quickly (by shortening 5V and GND prior to connecting it to the ESP8266 where it's running on), and I can configure it, but I just cannot get it out of AT mode. AT+RESET gives me "OK", but contrary to my HC-05, it doesn't switch from slow to fast blinking and is also not discoverable from my MacBook. 
I have tried AT+ORGL and AT+RENEW as well, but to no avail.

Does anyone have an idea how to get it working again? Because this way, it's kind of bricked.

Also, is there a way to make the device have a four digit pin only? When I use AT+PIN0000 it returns ERR, only when I use AT+PIN000000 it returns OK.

Comment: I don't know if Stack Overflow will be able to best answer this question.  Stack Overflow is more for programming questions.  You seem to be asking something that is more within the domain of questions answerable by [Electronics Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).  This might be in our wheelhouse, but you might get more focused eyes on it over there.

Comment: Thanks, I saw a few questions asked around the HC-05/06 here in the past, but will try Electronics Stack Exchange...